# Blazor app Reload after B2C authentication

Tags: blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly

Why does a Blazor app completely reload/restart after B2C Authentication?  Using Net 6.
[image]

Here is the callback:
[image]

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't solve the actual Reload problem (the console still displays duplicate 'Login Success' logs from the OnLoginSucceed method) but this solution does provide a more seamless user experience.

When you register the AAD B2C authentication, set the LoginMode to "Redirect"

```
options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "Redirect";
```

Adding this line when I registered the AddMsalAuthentication service gave me my expected behavior.

This way when you log in the Authentication screen won't be a pop-up but will redirect you to the AAD B2C Authentication page. On success the user will only experience one page refresh and it won't seem like there are duplicate refreshes taking place.

This is the solution I took for my application and I can accept this for my UX - hope this provides a similar result for your case.

Comment: At first I liked the pop up better, but after switching to redirect it provides a much better user experience so decided to switch.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/616079/index.html

In standard OAuth authentication the browser is redirected to a remote token server where the login takes place. The token server redirects back to the application with an access token the Blazor application uses (Bearer) to access secured resources.

Comment: I kinda understand the cause, but it leads to a horrid user experience. When logging in, right after the login screen disappears you can see that the app reacts to the successful login by updating the <AuthorizeView><Authorized>view on the page but then immediately reloads the app. Its like ripping the rug right out from under the user and making them wait another few seconds while the app reloads..